# evaluating Lebesgue integral 3

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A_{R,r}$ be a set with $0\lt r\lt R$
>   $$A_{R,r}= \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid (R-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2+z^2\le r^2\}$$
>   Evaluate $\lambda_3(A_{R,r})$

Answer:
I used Cavalieri's principle and set 
$$A_z=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2}\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2}\}$$
and then follows $$\lambda_3(A_{R,r})=\int_{-r}^{r} \lambda_2(A_z)dz$$
with
$$\lambda_2(A_z)=\int_{R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}^{R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} \lambda_1(B_x^z)dx$$
where 
$$B_x^z=\{y\in\mathbb R\mid (R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2})^2-x^2\le y^2\le (R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2})^2-x^2\}$$
hence
$$\lambda_1(B_x^z)=\int_{\sqrt{(R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2})^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{(R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2})^2-x^2}} dy=\sqrt{(R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2})^2-x^2}-\sqrt{(R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2})^2-x^2}$$

Comment: Shouldn't you rather be interested in regions $$R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2}\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leqslant R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2}\ ?$$

Comment: I think I did it, in the integral of $\lambda_2(A_z)$ or not?

Comment: Except that your $A_z$ seems to be defined by the inequality $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leqslant R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2},$$ which seems unrelated to the problem.

Comment: I changed $A_x$ and the boundaries of the integrals, too.

Comment: Is it right, now?

Comment: The steps are correct, now--but they might not be the most direct way to solve the exercise, in fact cylindrical coordinates $(x,y,z)=(u\cos t,u\sin t,z)$ with $u>0$ and $t$ in $(0,2\pi)$, come to mind...

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: I did it with cylindrical coordinates, are these boundaries right:$$\int_{0}^{2*\pi} dt\int_{0}^{r} dz\int_{R-\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}^{R+\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}u du$$ I am not sure by the bounds of $z$.

Comment: Use either $\int_{-r}^rdz$ or, by symmetry, $2\int_{0}^rdz$, the rest is correct.